# Fish Shell - function name conflicts with apt package in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apt, fish

I have created a fish function named *proot* but there is an Ubuntu package with the same name.

When I type 'proot' into my fish shell, I get

```
 ~> proot
The program 'proot' is currently not installed. You can install it by     typing:
sudo apt-get install proot
```

Running `functions -n` does show me my *proot* function, I just can't run it.

I have tried to run the equivalent of bash's `UNSET command_not_found_handle` (`set -e command_not_found_handle` in my config.fish), which should theoretically disable apt's prompting to install, but it doesn't seem to matter.

Is there a way to make a function name that conflicts with a package, or disable apt's prompting from within fish? (I have renamed to `groot` and confirmed that it works just fine.)

Answer (score 2):

*sigh* never mind. I can confirm that this does indeed work. A copy/paste error in my Puppet manifest meant I was copying two similarly named aliases from the same source file. So even though I had proot.fish it was defining a function named `sroot`.